# Window binding not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

my script reads something like this:

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    //some code
    //few more lines of code
});
```

This function works perfectly as intended in Chrome and Safari browsers. But Firefox for some reason ignores this function and does not work as intended.

Comment: Use `on()` and not `bind()`

Comment: Works for me using the demo from MDN: http://jsfiddle.net/55T2G/ You need to provide code that replicates the issue. http://SSCCE.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    //some code
    //few more lines of code
});
```

You can use:

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
    //some code
    //few more lines of code
}
```

As firefox is using W3C defined rules for history API, so you have to use this for firefox and it works in chrome, safari and other browsers as well.

Comment: it's preferable to append listeners, not to override them. use `window.addEventListener` instead.

Comment: @EliranMalka I agree.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState()
>   won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered
>   by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button (or
>   calling history.back() in JavaScript).
>
> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load.
>   Chrome and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but
>   Firefox doesn't.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/popstate

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying Chrome and Safari fire the event on page load **or** when the browser's back button is clicked?  If the former, it's because Chrome/Safari are out of compliance with the HTML5 specs => the event should never be fired on page load.  Up-vote https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63040 to get Google to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Please do Check that if you have coded `window.load()` more than once OR have called `.onload()` more than one time. This probably may work for IE but not for Chrome and fireFox.